# Ignoring data lines in R

Tags: r

So I have read in data using `readLine()` I'm needing to apply a function to every line in the list except for example lets say the lines before line 15 and after like 30.

How am I meant to cut this data out of my original text data?
I was thinking of maybe indexing the data I need like `data[15]` to `data[30]` and then using `lapply()` on the data within these bounds. I also thought about just deleting (or ignoring) the data lines unto line 15 and after line 30 but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: just user range-indexing `data[15:30]`. having the first 31 lines here (or a link to the file) would help tho

Comment: I would have guessed it would be `dat[ -(15:30) , ]` , i.e. exclusion of that range on the basis of line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep *only* lines 15-30, it's simply:

```
# write something to a text file

nrow(iris)

write.table(iris, 'temp.txt', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)

some_txt <- readLines(file('temp.txt'))[15:30]

length(some_txt)
```

If you want to keep everything *except* those lines then it's `some_txt <- readLines(file('temp.txt'))[-(15:30)]`.  We're a little confused which subset you're looking for.